# Android Facebook app request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-app-requests

I have implemented Facebook app request in android. Now i able to send request to user but my problem is that, When user select app request from facebook app it getting facebook error. Actually what i want, when user select app request it redirect to app or android market link. here i attached screens and code for app request. Please help me.

Request Code :

```
             if(facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                 // A request showing how to send extra data that could signify a gift
                 Bundle params = new Bundle();
                 params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");
                 params.putString("title", "cRoNy Invite friends");
                 params.putString("data", 
                                  "{\"badge_of_awesomeness\":\"1\"," +
                                  "\"social_karma\":\"5\"}");

                 facebook.dialog(App.this, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        final String returnId = values.getString("request");
                        if (returnId != null) {
                            // Show the request Id if request sent successfully
                            Log.e("CD","Request Id : "+ returnId);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                            "Request sent: " +  returnId, 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                        Log.e("CD","Facebook Error : "+ error);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Log.e("CD","Facebook Error : "+ e);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Show a message if the user cancelled the request
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 });
             } else {
                 // If the session is not valid show a message
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to login to use send requests.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
```

And Facebook Error Message :

[image]